# How to write unit tests in AngularJS using requirejs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

Iam using requirejs in my angularjs application.While writing unit tests I am getting errors.

this is my module defn

```
define(['angular', 'dropdown', 'authorizationController',
        'cropImageDirective', 'uniqueNameDirective', 'compareDirective',
        'accountNameService', 'uniqueEmailService',
        'angularRoute', 'angularAnimate', 'angularMaterial',
        'angularAria', 'angularMessages', 'uiBootstrap', 'imageCrop'],
    function (angular, dropdown, authorizationController,
              cropImageDirective, uniqueNameDirective, compareDirective,
              accountNameService, uniqueEmailService,
              angularRoute, angularAnimate, angularMaterial,
              angularAria, angularMessages, uiBootstrap, imageCrop) {

        // Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
        var app = angular.module("ctxadmauth", ['authorization.controllers',
            'cropImage.directives', 'uniqueNames.directives', 'compare.directive',
            'accountName.services', 'uniqueEmail.services',
            'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ngMaterial', 'ngAria', 'ngMessages', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngImgCrop']);

        return app;
    });
```

and this is my controller spec--

```
describe('test suite for authorization module authorization controller', function () {

    var $scope, $rootScope, ctrl, $httpBackend, controller, $location, $window, $interval, $mdDialog;

    //beforeEach(angular.module('ctxadmauth'));
    beforeEach(module('authorization.controllers'));

    beforeEach(
        inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _$httpBackend_, _$location_, _$window_, _$interval_, _$mdDialog_) {
            // create a scope object for us to use.
            $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            controller = _$controller_;
            $location = _$location_;
            $window = _$window_;
            $interval = _$interval_;
            $mdDialog = _$mdDialog_;

            ctrl = controller('authorizationController', {
                $scope: $scope,
                $rootScope: $rootScope

            });
        })
    );

    describe('controller methods', function () {

        it('should authorization controller to be defined ', function () {
            //spec body
            expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();
        });

        it('should authorization controller calls login account page ', function () {

            expect($scope.loginAccount()).toBeDefined();
            $scope.loginAccount();
            expect($location.path()).toEqual('/admin/login/account');
        });

        it('should authorization controller calls forgot password page ', function () {
            $scope.forgotPassword();
            expect($location.path()).toMatch('/admin/forgotpassword');

        });
    });
});
```

previously also I have done in the same way,But I didn't use requirejs .That time I was succeeded .Now karma is not identifying module...in beforeeach(module(ctxadmauth)).Its saying injection error

Please help me somebody who are doing angularjs+requirejs combination and how to write unit tests in this combo